# Error The statement did not return a result set

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,value="update tbl_runningNumber set autoNum= autoNum+1 where cycle=:cycle and module=:module")
String updateByCycle(@Param ("module")String module,@Param("cycle") int cycle);
```

I want to update data form spring to database
when i click on update at database is work normal but at my spring error messages

```
2023-02-01 16:17:47.651  WARN 21588 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2023-02-01 16:17:47.651 ERROR 21588 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The statement did not return a result set.
```

Comment: Well, an `update` statement doesn't return a value, yet the return type of your method is `String`. What do you expect that to return?

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery=true,value="update tbl_runningNumber set autoNum= autoNum+1 where cycle=:cycle and module=:module")
String updateByCycle(@Param ("module")String module,@Param("cycle") int cycle);

can i change my return String to another one ....? brother

Comment: when i follow this answer the error show ( Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is )

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any modifications you attempted and the complete stack trace & error message that you got. Giving us just a sliver of the error message and hoping that someone can guess what went wrong in the code that you didn't show is us a bit rude, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make return type for the method to `void` as the update query does not return anything.

Also for update query you should annotate method with below annotations along with `@Query`.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
```

Comment: void updateByCycle(String module, int cycle);

Like this is error too brother

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate your update method with [`@Modifying`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html) annotation.

Comment: i use jpa.repository.Modifying annotaion but is show another error ( Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is )